# MSBuild Pivoting ItemGroup on Delimited String

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I have an ItemGroup of installers and each one contains a Property which is the name of out output folder (delimited) like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Installers Include="Installer1.msi">
    <Folders>Folder1,Folder4</Folders>
  </Installers>

  <Installers Include="Installer2.msi">
    <Folders>Folder1,Folder2,Folder3,Folder4</Folders>
  </Installers>
</ItemGroup>
```

I would like to be able to copy each installer into each folder that's specified.  I've been back and forth trying to figure out a way to add additional metadata to Installers, but just can't seem to get a final list of something like this:

1. Installer1.msi:Folder1
2. Installer1.msi:Folder4
3. Installer2.msi:Folder1
4. Installer2.msi:Folder2
5. Installer2.msi:Folder3
6. Installer2.msi:Folder4

So I could execute something like this:

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(Installers)" DestinationFolder="%(Installers.Folder)" />
```

I know I can modify my ItemGroup to this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Installers Include="Installer1.msi">
    <Folder>Folder1</Folder>
  </Installers>
  <Installers Include="Installer1.msi">
    <Folder>Folder4</Folder>
  </Installers>

  <Installers Include="Installer2.msi">
    <Folder>Folder1</Folder>
  </Installers>
  <Installers Include="Installer2.msi">
    <Folder>Folder2</Folder>
  </Installers>
  <Installers Include="Installer2.msi">
    <Folder>Folder3</Folder>
  </Installers>
  <Installers Include="Installer2.msi">
    <Folder>Folder4</Folder>
  </Installers>
</ItemGroup>
```

but I'd rather not, as that's what we have now and people always miss things (because it's so verbose).

Comment: I guess the other requirement I would like, is I would like this to work for N-Folders.  E.g. I don't want to have to know my folder names a priori, I'd prefer to just discover them because they're in the Folders property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate folder names with semicolons, then invert the installer and folder values:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Inversionator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Folders Include="Folder1;Folder4">
            <Installer>Installer1.msi</Installer>
        </Folders>
        <Folders Include="Folder1;Folder2;Folder3;Folder4">
            <Installer>Installer2.msi</Installer>
        </Folders>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Inversionator">
        <Message Text="%(Folders.Installer) %(Folders.Identity) " Importance="high" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Output for the  task is now:

```
Installer1.msi Folder1
Installer1.msi Folder4
Installer2.msi Folder1
Installer2.msi Folder2
Installer2.msi Folder3
Installer2.msi Folder4
```

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance.  I took a while to ponder if this would satisfy all my aesthetic requirements and upon reflection, determined it did!